# apache/php hangs: semop?

Tags: php, apache, php-5.2

I am writing a wordpress plugin to include a custom made single sign-on.

I have a problem I can not reproduce but it happens often: Sometimes you login, click a another page and this page keeps loading for ever. Also all other request from the same session will stuck from this time. Restarting apache fixes it but is not a real solution.

The server has not a lot traffic so only a few apache processes are running. If I dig into them I see many stucked with `semop`:

```
(gdb) bt
#0  0x00002af60c22b2d7 in semop () from /lib64/libc.so.6
#1  0x00002af60bbf612c in ?? () from /usr/lib64/libapr-1.so.0
#2  0x000055555559e614 in ?? () from /usr/sbin/httpd2-prefork
#3  0x000055555559e9ea in ?? () from /usr/sbin/httpd2-prefork
#4  0x000055555559f25d in ap_mpm_run () from /usr/sbin/httpd2-prefork
#5  0x000055555557a080 in main () from /usr/sbin/httpd2-prefork
```

looks like they are waiting for a file:

```
strace -p 3069
....
read(7, 0x7fff16a04df7, 1)              = -1 EAGAIN (Resource temporarily unavailable)
semop(286162952, 0x2af60bd07dc0, 1 <unfinished ...>
```

`read(7 ,..)` points to a pipe:

```
# ls -la /proc/3069/fd/7
lr-x------ 1 root   root 64 Nov  7 17:24 7 -> pipe:[157329520]
```

That pipe is used by all the apache processes:

```
# lsof | grep 157329520
httpd2-pr  2430       root    7r     FIFO                0,5             157329520 pipe
httpd2-pr  2430       root    8w     FIFO                0,5             157329520 pipe
httpd2-pr  3061     wwwrun    7r     FIFO                0,5             157329520 pipe
httpd2-pr  3061     wwwrun    8w     FIFO                0,5             157329520 pipe
...
```

It might be not related to the problem but I still wounder what kind of pipe this is.

People here are guessing it's not a server problem after all but from what I see in the backtrace PHP is not even called yet. No libphp5.so at all.

I would love to post some PHP code for you to look at, but I just don't know which part... My script makes a curl call to another script in the same session. Maybe this is creating some kind of blocking? Or could it be https problem?

I really can't tell if it is PHP or Apache but the key to the problem might be to understand what apache is doing here.

Any idea how to fix or debug this?

Comment: I guess it's just a pipe that connect's to processses ... like when you do `cat foo | cat`. In this case apache seems to communicate with itself. I am not sure if the problem is related to apache.

Comment: It doesn't look like a server configuration problem, but more likely some bad PHP *code* like the OP mentioned.  If you're pretty well convinced it's not the actual PHP code but rather a problem in the PHP session handler feel free to ask on SF about that piece (we'd need to know what session handler you're using to be of any help - there are a few options, including "custom" ones that might be homegrown PHP that needs debugging).

Comment: Funny that the question gets moved to SF and now everyone is saying it's not a server problem :) I never said it is PHP or apache, I ask what it might be. I would have accepted "it's not a server problem, see stackoverflow.com/questions/264266/debugging-hung-php"; as an answer if someone can tell me how you got to this. For me that makes no sense. If it's a PHP problem how comes the callstack does not contain php_execute_script or libphp5.so? Looks to me like PHP is not even called yet. I really think this question needs to be reopened, please.

Comment: @Pekka yes, sure. I only do a quick db query if the token is still valid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the `strace` output it looks like it is waiting for file-pointer number seven. You can find out which file this is by looking for a line like

```
open("/foo/bar", ......)     = 7
```

somewhere before the `read` call.

Comment: Thank you. I did that with `ls -la /proc/3069/fd/7` but it's a pipe not a read file. See my last update but I will have a look for the `open()`. Might tell me something about the pipe.